# Changing author info in git commit message

Tags: git

So my problem is - I want to change email domain of author in the commit message from someDomain.com to myDomain.net and to change their name so it starts with the capital letter. I want to apply that change on every commit message of every single one commit of my current branch. How can I do that using git filter-branch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-and-committer-name-and-e-mail-of-multiple-commits-in-git)

Comment: Compare with https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/1256452 (not quite the same question). Are there parts of that answer that you don't understand, that once you do understand, that answer plus this will get you what you want?

Comment: Thanks guys, that was about the email but how can I change the name so it starts with the capital letter ?

Comment: The other question is about re-copying commits to new commits with changed ***name and*** email address.